# T-SQL return different row value for MIN and MAX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, min

I have some data that looks like this:

```
LA Code Local_Authority         Region          Spend per pupil
----------------------------------------------------------------
831     Derby                   East Midlands   4370
830     Derbyshire              East Midlands   4600
822     Bedford                 East of England 4694
873     Cambridgeshire          East of England 4455
301     Barking & Dagenham      London          5377
302     Barnet                  London          4965
330     Birmingham              West Midlands   5483
331     Coventry                West Midlands   4970
```

I want to create a summary table that shows a region, and the minimum spend by a local authority and the maximum spend, so something like this:

```
Region            Min_LA_Name    Min_Amount   Max_LA_Name        Max_Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
East Midlands     Derby          4370         Derbyshire         4600
East of England   Cambridgeshire 4455         Bedford            4694
London            Barnet         4965         Barking & Dagenham 5377
West Midlands     Coventry       4970         Birmingham         4970
```

I have got as far as the following code:

```
SELECT 
    Region,
    (SELECT Local_Authority 
     FROM LASpendPerPupil_df 
     GROUP BY REGION 
     HAVING MIN("Spend per pupil")) AS Min_LA_Name, 
    MIN("Spend per pupil") AS Min_Amount,
    (SELECT Local_Authority 
     FROM LASpendPerPupil_df 
     GROUP BY REGION 
     HAVING MAX("Spend per pupil")) AS Max_LA_Name,
    MAX("Spend per pupil") AS Max_Amount
FROM
    LASpendPerPupil_df
GROUP BY 
    REGION;
```

I am getting the correct output for the minimum and maximum values, but the Local Authority name columns are just repeating the minimum and maximum name for the first region, so like this:

```
Region            Min_LA_Name    Min_Amount   Max_LA_Name       Max_Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
East Midlands     Derby          4370         Derbyshire         4600
East of England   Derby          4455         Derbyshire         4694
London            Derby          4965         Derbyshire         5377
West Midlands     Derby          4970         Derbyshire         4970
```

Can anyone help me fix this? I am a Stack Overflow newbie and new to SQL so apologies if I've not posted correctly.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to be actually correct, with sample data/script.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Tmp 

CREATE TABLE #Tmp (
    [LA Code] int
    , Local_Authority VARCHAR(50)
    , Region VARCHAR(50)
    , [Spend per pupil] INT);   

INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES
(831,'Derby','East Midlands',4370),
(830,'Derbyshire','East Midlands', 4600),
(822,'Bedford','East of England', 4694),
(873,'Cambridgeshire','East of England', 4455),
(301,'Barking & Dagenham','London',5377),
(302,'Barnet','London',4965),
(330,'Birmingham','West Midlands',5483),
(331,'Coventry','West Midlands',4970)

SELECT
    x.Region
    , (SELECT Local_Authority 
        FROM #Tmp WHERE Region=x.Region AND [Spend per pupil]=MaxSpend) AS MaxAuth
    , MaxSpend
    , (SELECT Local_Authority 
        FROM #Tmp WHERE Region=x.Region AND [Spend per pupil]=MinSpend) AS MinAuth
    , MinSpend 
FROM
    (SELECT Region, MAX([Spend per pupil]) AS MaxSpend 
    FROM #Tmp GROUP BY Region) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT Region, MIN([Spend per pupil]) AS MinSpend 
    FROM #Tmp GROUP BY Region) y on x.Region = y.region
```

[image]

Comment: @ChristinaBriggs Youre welcome. I have gotten in the habit of treating select statements as tables due to alot of calculations i have to do in larger queries. This requires a lot of outer joins to make sure my data is right in each subset before "putting it together."  This is a really awesome article, i suggest readin it  https://blog.jooq.org/2016/04/25/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/

Comment: @DougCoats you sure this works? because you can't take a max of local authority, either that has to included in group by (which we don't need) or else it won't work. Correct me if I am wrong, but we can only take variables which can be aggregated in select statement except the variable in group by

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
select a.region,b.la_name as min_la_name,a.min_amount,c.la_name as max_la_name,a.max_amount
from
(select region,min([SPEND PER PUPIL])  as min_amount, max([SPEND PER PUPIL]) as max_amount
from your_table
group by region ) a
left join
your_table b
on a.region = b.region and a.min_amount = b.[SPEND PER PUPIL]
left join
your_table c
on a.region = c.region and a.max_amount = c.[SPEND PER PUPIL];
```

Do let me know in case of any clarifications

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this post.  I had a go but I can't get the code to run, I get an error saying "no such column: b.amount"

Comment: You need to use your column spend per pupil

Comment: Great!  Thanks very much, sorry it took me a bit of editing to get everything in the right place.

Comment: I am glad you got the logic right, That's the whole purpose.